# VT-x is not available when trying to run virtual box

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I have a Lenovo W510 with windows 2008 R2 installed.

I run Hyper-V on this machine without problems, virtualization is enabled in order to do this.

I am now trying to run virtual box on this machine and get the error: VT-x is not available

Anyone know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot run Hyper-V and virtual box simultaneously.  Any application that uses the virtualization-specific instruction sets on the CPU does so wholesale and therefore locks other programs out of using them.  The only way to use another virtual software is to either deactivate Hyper-V or make sure that the software does not make use of the virtualization instructions.  You'd have to check with the software developers to figure out how to do the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried stopping the 3 hyper-V services and setting them to manual startup, I then restarted the machine. Still did not work. Do I need to remove the Hyper-V role from the server?

Comment: @Shiraz, Hyper-V is **not a service**, it's a hypervisor. You need to remove the Role in Server Manager if you want Hyper-V gone (the same way you installed it, more than likely).

Comment: @Chris, removing the Hyper-V role worked

Comment: There are messages that it is still possible: http://www.eightforums.com/virtualization/48077-hyper-v-vmware-same-machine.html Kari's post at 15 Jun 2014